# something about process schedule by OS?

Tags: c, process, io, operating-system, fork

I write the following codes and run it in my linux.Everytime after fork the terminals print two PID, which shows both processes are scheduled by the OS, and then it is time for "scanf" to execute, both processes are blocked waiting for the input.However every time I put a number, and then I get the same PID printed on the terminal. **Does it mean the same process is invoked by the OS when a terminal IO meets, or something else happens?**

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    int num;

    if(fork() >= 0)
    {
       printf("%x\n",getpid());
       while(1)
       {
          if(scanf("%d",&num) != EOF)
          {
             printf("%x\n",getpid());
          }
       }
    }
    printf("\nit is over:%x\n", getpid());
}
```

Comment: You are grouping the test case for whether you are in the parent process and the child process together. `fork()` returns the PID of the child process to the parent (> 0) and `fork()` returns 0 to the child.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Hunter McMillen already noted in comments you are grouping the cases for the parent and child. Now both of them are scheduled as noted by different `PID`s outputted and both of them are now waiting at `scanf`. As soon as you enter data, you are seeing only one `PID`, because the input you entered was part of one process. **Other process ( can be parent or child ) is still waiting for you to enter something**. Now, even though your terminal is flooded by a single `PID`, continuously outputted by one process, try entering some data again and press enter. Now you can see both `PID`s being printed!

Comment: No matter how many times I enter data and press enter, I get the same PID printed on the terminal

Comment: @venus.w It is just a coincidence that you are seeing the same PID. On my PC, I am able to see both PIDs almost in equal ratio. Do one thing. Instead of entering number for `scanf`, enter a `char` and press ENTER. `scanf` will go mad and PID will be printed infinitely in one process. Again enter one more `char` and press enter. Now you'll see both PIDs shuffling around infinitely

Comment: I run my program on ubuntu, what's your OS, maybe it depends on the OS.

Comment: Even I am on Ubuntu 11.10. OS should not matter. Did you try entering a character instead of a number as I suggested?

Answer (score 0):

This is because, in the if() statement, fork() creates child process and runs in an infinite loop. There's a concept of parent process, the parent of child process created using fork() system call. The statement after if() ends, belongs to parent process and here, it will execute only after child process ends. That's why you get the same process ID, that is of child process.

Comment: There is no `wait` here. So the parent continues its execution after `fork` and does not `wait` for the child to end to begin its execution. Parent and Child execute independently of each other. Consult http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_(operating_system)